# Is it right to store mysql fetch result in a text file using php filing and load when needed inside the view using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I designed my Model View Controller. What i want to do is to store mysql fetched query data into php file or localStorage or sessionStorage, so that the stored information can be reused without bothering database over and over. I can save this information into a php session as well but using a lot of sessions could cause your server slow down.

Is this a good practice in this particular case to store information inside any of these said storages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of what you're trying to do is called "caching".  Here's an article on a simple way to do it, kind of like what you're talking about: http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/.

Whether or not it's "good practice" depends largely on your application.  If it's a SQL query who's results don't change often (you might want to re-think why you're doing a query in those cases) and a complicated query that is very time consuming to run then go for it.  I would advise against doing it unless that criteria apply because there's a reason you're using a database: you want it to be dynamic.  Most databases can handle a lot of queries and your queries and data can be optimized for queries that you'll be running pretty often.

Do you notice it taking a long time to run the query? Have you isolated the problem to the database?  Most importantly: does the data change very often and do your users care that their views won't be up to date?

I should add, it's VERY rarely a good idea to store anything like this inside of session storage. The only things you'd use session storage for is for a user name or an anonymous user's shopping cart. Never for query caching.

Answer (score 0):

No not at all. Your database is the fastest and most efficient at these tasks, so using something like a session to store data is a bad idea. You can look into persistent objects though, with an ORM like [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org).